# MySQLi not returning results from database

Tags: php, sql, select, mysqli

This is my code:

```
<?php

include('config.php');

$mysqli = new mysqli($db['host'], $db['user'], $db['pass'], $db['name']);
if ($mysqli->connect_error)
    throw new Exception('Couldn\'t connect to MySQL: ' . $mysqli->connect_error);

// Check for a ID parameter
if(isset($_GET['id']) && !empty($_GET['id']))
{
    $skinId = (int)$_GET['id'];

    // Build a query to get skin info from the database
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare('SELECT name, description, author, timestamp, url FROM `skins` WHERE id=?');
    $stmt->bind_param('i', $skinId);

    // Execute query
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($result['name'], $result['desc'], $result['auth'], $result['time'], $result['url']);

    echo $result['name'];
} else {
    // Show a 404 page
    echo "bad";
}

$mysqli->close();

?>
```

When this is run, I get no results back. I can verify that `$skinId` does hold a valid skin ID when I try, and it's not an empty variable. When I run the same statement on localhost using phpMyAdmin, I get the proper row back with all the information requested in the query. When I do `print_r($result)` I get this:

```
Array
(
    [name] => 
    [desc] => 
    [auth] => 
    [time] => 
    [url] => 
)
```

Anyone know what's going on? Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: Are you sure that id is in the database?

Answer (score 1):

you should do $stmt->fetch() after the $stmt->bind_result command in order to fetch the data from the database to the your result array

Comment: Dammit! Knew it'd be something simple. Thank you :)